# HTML table semantic structure - alternative data on rows

Tags: html, html-table, css-tables, semantic-markup

This is more of a semantics questions as I know I can do it but **should I?**

I have a load of data that I need to display on a page. It's laid out as tabular data like so:

```
| Reference | Name | Date | Status | Type |
```

This is one of the only use cases where HTML tables actually should be used however…

Each row can be clicked on and then it will expand to show more info about that booking in the row below. With all rows opened the structure will look like:

```
| Reference | Name | Date | Status | Type |
| Info |
| Reference | Name | Date | Status | Type |
| Info |
| Reference | Name | Date | Status | Type |
| Info |
```

Without using some CSS or JS hackery to force a new row, I'd need to layout the HTML with the Info cell in its own row spanning all columns. This doesn't seem very semantic to me.

Now I'm wondering whether that's fine, or should I skip using tables all together, or has anyone got a better idea?

Comment: You want to show more info when clicked, but without hackery? In that case, you should refine what you mean by hackery, otherwise any answer won't stand a chance. I mean, e.g. you don't want to use JS to add a `colspan` attribute, that much is obvious. So what _do_ you want to allow?

Comment: I want to layout the HTML without trickery. I'm fine with using JS for opening the info

Comment: Anyway, IMHO I don't see why using colspan would qualify as not semantic. That's what those attributes are for, otherwise they would long have been deprecated.

Comment: The typographic layout shown for the structure complete with detailed information *is not a table*; it is a list of items, where each item consists of a one-row table and a paragraph of supplementary information.

Comment: @MrLister - colspan is fine. I'd need to force that data onto a new row though by either stripping out a load of default table styles with CSS or inserting more HTML with JS. Both are not ideal

Comment: @AlexP - What's the semantic value of a one-row table? Would that be weird having lots of separate tables of the data structure? I'm liking this idea so far though

Comment: @AlexP Supplementary information is also data. And if it comes from the same table in the same database, it is also tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always set `table`, `tbody`, `tr` and `td` to `display: block` and then lay out the desired structure in CSS, using the HTML tags as pure structural markup:

```html
<html>

  <title>Testing table layout</title>

  <style>

    table, tbody, tr, td {
      display: block;
    }
    table {
      width: 610px;
    }
    tbody, tr {
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
    }
    td {
      float: left;
      width: 33%;
    }
    td.extra {
      clear: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    /* Colors to make cells visible */
    td { background: #FFEEEE; }
    td+td { background: #EEFFEE; }
    td+td+td { background: #EEFFFF; }
    td+td+td+td { background: #EEDDFF; }

  </style>

  <body>

    <table>

      <tr valign="baseline">

        <td>Left cell</td>

        <td>Middle cell</td>

        <td>Right cell</td>

        <td class="extra">Supplementary cell</td>

      </tr>

      <tr valign="baseline">

        <td>Left cell</td>

        <td>Middle cell</td>

        <td>Right cell</td>

        <td class="extra">Supplementary cell</td>

      </tr>

      <tr valign="baseline">

        <td>Left cell</td>

        <td>Middle cell</td>

        <td>Right cell</td>

        <td class="extra">Supplementary cell</td>

      </tr>

    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

In real life you will of course limit this to a certain class of tables. The supplementary data in the last cell would of course be initially `display: none` and will get `display: block` only when needed.

Comment: I suppose this does make the most sense. Thanks